# GCP forward all external ports to one local port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

I'm trying to find out if GCP supports the ability to forward **ALL** ports to a single one.

Currently I'm "manually" setting firewall rules on each instance using the following iptable rule.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1:65535 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10000
```

This is not fun to manage because I'm using docker and don't want to manage the VM directly.

The flow I'm trying to implement is as follows:

- Received TCP request (Ingres)
- Load balance request (GCP TCP-LB)
- Redirect **ALL** requests to port `10000` (???)
- Docker container listening on port `10000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these two options:

1.- Using a VM instance as a bastion host and be used as [NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway) for your other instances.

2.- Use [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gce-example) directly or with [protocol forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding) that will be something similar to what you are trying to implement.